# GCC preprocessor macro and "#pragma GCC unroll"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

Is there another mechanism to get the GCC preprocessor to do this:

```
#define LIMIT  16
#pragma GCC unroll LIMIT
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < LIMIT; ++ii) {
  ...
```

That code hits an error:

```
/path/to/my/file.c:100:20 error: 'LIMIT' undeclared (first use in this function)
  100 | #pragma GCC unroll LIMIT
      |                    ^~~~~
```

gcc [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Loop-Specific-Pragmas.html) says that this wants `an integer constant expression specifying the unrolling factor`.  I believe that my macro is an "integer constant expression", but...

My compiler is: `riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc (g2ee5e430018) 12.2.0`.

Comment: Does it work if you use `#pragma GCC unroll 16`?  What about if you use `#pragma GCC unroll (8+8)`?

Comment: Both of those work @JonathanLeffler. I can't hardcode it because it's generated code, with different sizes.  I'm using the solution posted below.  Thanks!

Comment: Curiously, clang doesn't complain about it. It does complain if I write `#pragma GCC unroll gibberish` though.

Comment: I would probably call this yet another gcc bug. And one that's been around since version 8 when the pragma seems to have been introduced. gcc 8 does give a diagnostic about providing an integer constant expression. It does accept `8+8` but not a pre-processor constant expanding into an integer.

Comment: #pragmas are not touched by the preprocessor.

Comment: See C11 [§6.10.6 The `#pragma` directive](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.6).  The footnote says: _An implementation is not required to perform macro replacement in pragmas, but it is permitted except for in standard pragmas (where STDC immediately follows pragma)._. So GCC is within its rights not to attempt macro expansion; other compilers are within their rights if they do so.  Portable code cannot assume macro expansion will occur.  C23 and C18 say very much the same.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, That is the killer answer. That explains why GCC doesn't work, but Clang does! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` and `constexpr` (in case you can use C++) seems to work (tested with gcc 13.2 on https://godbolt.org/).

```
const int x = 5;
#pragma GCC unroll x
for (std::size_t ii = 0; ii < x; ++ii) {
```

Comment: That works!  Thanks!  Color me puzzled.  I thought that the preprocessor macro would be treated as a constant integer.  Hmm....

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the `#pragma` directive, the `_Pragma` operator can be used. It is a bit tricky to get the argument expanded correctly, but this should work for both C and C++ (see example on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/qh4ebE8v1)):

```
#define STRING(V) #V
#define MAKE_PRAGMA(S) _Pragma(S)
#define UNROLL(N) MAKE_PRAGMA(STRING(GCC unroll N))

#define LIMIT 16
...
UNROLL(LIMIT)
for (size_t ii = 0; ii < LIMIT; ++ii) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Expanding on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78071873/gcc-preprocessor-macro-and-pragma-gcc-unroll?noredirect=1#comment137644499_78071873).*</sup>

The C11 standard [§6.10.6 The `#pragma` directive](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.6) says:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
> # pragma pp-tokens-opt new-line
> ```
>
> where the preprocessing token `STDC` does not immediately follow pragma in the directive (prior to any macro replacement)<sup>174)</sup> causes the implementation to behave in an implementation-defined manner. The behavior might cause translation to fail or cause the translator or the resulting program to behave in a non-conforming manner. Any such pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored.
>
> If the preprocessing token `STDC` does immediately follow `pragma` in the directive (prior to any macro replacement), then no macro replacement is performed on the directive, and the directive shall have one of the following forms<sup>175)</sup> whose meanings are described elsewhere:
>
> ```
> #pragma STDC FP_CONTRACT on-off-switch
> #pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on-off-switch
> #pragma STDC CX_LIMITED_RANGE on-off-switch
> on-off-switch: one of
>             ON     OFF           DEFAULT
> ```

and footnote 174 says:

> An implementation is not required to perform macro replacement in pragmas, but it is permitted except for in standard pragmas (where `STDC` immediately follows `pragma`). If the result of macro replacement in a non-standard pragma has the same form as a standard pragma, the behavior is still implementation-defined; an implementation is permitted to behave as if it were the standard pragma, but is not required to.

(Footnote 175 links to text reserving `#pragma STDC …` for future use by the standard.)

Footnote 174 is crucial.  It means that GCC is within its rights not to attempt macro expansion; other compilers are within their rights if they do so.  Both are compliant with the C standard.

- **Portable code cannot assume macro expansion will occur in a `#pragma` directive.**

C23 and C18 say very much the same thing.

What you do about this depends on your requirements.  However, generating a `_Pragma` operator (see [§6.10.9 Pragma operator](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.9)) is probably the best (most portable and reliable) way — as suggested by [nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11993121/nielsen) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78074836/15168).  An example in the standard shows building a string with macro replacement, etc.